# Is there formula to quickly autofill only the first number in a range?

Tags: excel-formula

Below is an example of the list of numbers I need to create exactly as they appear.

```
401-409
501-509
601-609
701-709
```

I need to do this all the way up to 3901-3909 but can't get excel to only replace the first digits and leave the rest.

Comment: Starting in row 4, you can use formula `=Row() & "01-" & Row() & "09"` copy down to row 39.

Comment: @JNevill You sir are a genius. That worked perfectly.

Comment: @ScottCraner below is the genius. My solution is a hack. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first cell:

```
=(ROW(1:1)-1)*100+401 & "-" & (ROW(1:1)-1)*100+409
```

and copy down